# How can I find the python client library for a gcloud command?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, client-library

To write a Python script to collect various details about all projects deployed in the organization, how can we find which shared-vpc host project/network is being used?

There's a **gcloud** command that provides details

```bash
gcloud compute shared-vpc get-host-project strong-bad-2g0v

## provides results
results
kind: compute#project
name: shared-vpc-host-52ey86a9
```

However, I want to use Python for the script, so following the docs on how to use the Python Client and searching **Google Cloud Python Client** [repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python) for "shared-vpc" or "vpc" doesn't provide relevant results. Looking under /compute_v1 (assuming a similar structure as **gcloud**), doesn't show results for "shared-vpc" or "vpc"

Answer (score 1):

Using the flag `--log-http` with cloud provides more details about the API being called.

```bash
gcloud  compute shared-vpc get-host-project strong-bad-2g0v --log-http

##==== request start ====
uri: https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/strong-bad-2g0v/getXpnHost?alt=json
method: GET
```

seeing that the path element "getXpnHost", return to **Google Cloud Python Client** [repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-compute) and search and found examples.

Comment: Link to the Python documentation: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.projects.ProjectsClient#google_cloud_compute_v1_services_projects_ProjectsClient_get_xpn_host List of Python SDKs: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference